# Retrieving keys from a savedinstancestate when a user navigates away from an activity and then back

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

I'm having a problem with SavedInstanceStates. In the Main Activity of my app, a listview is populated with names from a database. When you click on one of the names, a new activity is opened, which shows another listview drawn from a separate database and details various information about the person. The items on this listview are only shown if their characterID, set according to the person whose name they are created under, and the id of the person in the original database match. So long story short, you can create a person Trevor, there are then a number of pieces of information shown specific to Trevor when you click on Trevor. You can also click on those pieces of information to open a new activity and edit that info/ do stuff with the info. I did this by saving the Uri of the person clicked with setData, and then getting that uri with getData and parsing the id from it for my second query.

When a user clicks a piece of information about Trevor and it opens in a new activity, the variable containing the id is destroyed as is the data I set in the first activity. So when I click back, it crashes due to a NullPointerException. So I now check if the data from getData() is null before performing my database query. But that just leaves the listview empty since it has no id to use when querying the database.

So I tried to used onSaveInstanceState to save the characterId variable. But using onRestoreInstanceState doesn't seem to work. Navigating to the third activity, and then finishing it by clicking back, does not seem to call onRestoreInstanceState. I also tried to check if the savedInstanceState is null in onCreate, see if it contains they key I set, and then withdraw it, but the savedInstanceState is null in onCreate whether Im first navigating to it, or hitting the back button to return to it.  I've looked around for a few hours trying to figure out the answer. Is this the wrong tool for the job? Am I missing something?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)    {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(savedCIdString)) {
            characterId = savedInstanceState.getInt(savedCIdString);
        }...
```

A snippet of my onCreate where I try to retrieve the variable, but SavedInstanceState is null when I first navigate to it, and when I press back from the activity after it.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putInt(savedCIdString, characterId);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    characterId = savedInstanceState.getInt(savedCIdString);
}
```

Comment: I'm becoming convinced I'm using the wrong tool and misunderstood the intent of onSaveInstanceState, but my only other idea is to pass the uri in as data to the third activity, then pass it back to the second, but I don't know how to set the data in the onBackPressed method. Any ideas?